# Getting StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION from Tensorflow serving server: Serving signature key "tensorflow/serving/predict" not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Getting following error from my python grpc client when trying to connect to the tf-serving server:

```
<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
details = "Serving signature key "tensorflow/serving/predict" not found."
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1540559424.720048798","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1099,"grpc_message":"Serving signature key "tensorflow/serving/predict" not found.","grpc_status":9}"
>
```

I believe this means when I build the servables the method name was wrong. But I see that in my servable model builder script I am using the correct name.

```
prediction_signature = tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
        inputs=input_signature,
        outputs=output_signature,
        method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)

    builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(os.path.join(output_path, str(version_number)))
```

What can be the reason for this error at client side?

Comment: If possible for you, can you share the Client Code so that we can try resolving the issue. Also, please share the Saved_Model_CLI, so that we can understand the SignatureDefs applicable for this model.